# Apps don't return

Tags: java, android, launcher, homescreen

I have written `custom home screen` app from which I am launching apps.

The `main problem` is the `opened apps doesn't return to my home screen app`, instead they go to the `launcher home screen`, even though I have set my home screen app as `default home screen`. I want these apps to return to my home screen. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you check documentation for the getLaunchIntentForPackage(..) method you see

> "Returns either a fully-qualified Intent that can be used to launch
>   the main activity in the package, or null if the package does not
>   contain such an activity. "

That's pretty self explaining.. your "app package name" is not correct, it might be for some apps but not for others.

try something like

```
PackageManager pManager = getPackageManager();  
List<PackageInfo> packs = pManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_INSTALLED_PACKAGES);  
 for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {  
   if(pi.packageName.toLowerCase().contains("app package name") )
{
     Intent intent = pManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pi.packageName); 
     if (intent != null)  
       startActivity(intent);  
    }
 }
```

Comment: This problem was solved, The real problem is not returning to default home screen

Comment: Well you should ask one question at a time and not change/update it once you solve the problem...